# How to use where when variable not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want use `where` when input variable is not null.

For example, when `@custid` is not null create this query:

```
Select * 
from customers 
where custid = @custid
```

and when `@custid` is null, then use this query instead:

```
Select * 
from customers
```

How can I do this?

I searched on google, but haven't found any similar answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
Select * 
from customers 
where @custid IS NULL OR custid=@custid
```

In this case if your variable is null only the condition `@custid IS NULL` will be evaluated and you get query identical to `Select * from customers`

If your variable is not null then condition `@custid IS NULL` is false and your query is identical to `Select * from customers where custid=@custid`

Answer (score 0):

I use a SqlBuilder class and provide filters that attach the WHERE clauses programmatically.

So the SqlBuilder class would look like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SqlBuilder.GetSql(null));
        Console.WriteLine(SqlBuilder.GetSql("CUSTOMER_ID"));
    }

    public class SqlBuilder{

        private static string _baseSql = "select * from customers";

        public static string GetSql(string customerId){
            var final = _baseSql;
            if(customerId != null)
                final += " WHERE custId=@custId";
            return final;
        }
    }
}
```

This can also be made generic through the use of parameters and enums.

Comment: Sounds like you've written part of an ORM, is there any reason you wouldn't just use a lightweight ORM instead?

Comment: I actually use this with Dapper. The current DB I use has really bad names for columns, so I have to rename them to make the code readable. It is also in DB2 so there are many ORMs that do not generate the SQL properly.